# replacingOccurrences not working on Device

Tags: ios, swift

I made a trimming whitespace code to remove whitespace in the textfield input, but here is a problem, on the emulator it works fine and removes whitespace but on the device, it won't work at all here is my code:

```
var number = numberTxtField.text
if number!.hasPrefix("+98") {
    let start = number!.index(number!.startIndex, offsetBy: 0);
    let end = number!.index(number!.startIndex, offsetBy: 3);
    number!.replaceSubrange(start..<end, with: "0")
    self.trimmed = number!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    print(self.trimmed)
    let pattern = "^[0-9]+$"
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self MATCHES [c] %@", pattern)
    if predicate.evaluate(with: self.trimmed) {
        print("Valid")
        if self.trimmed == nil && self.trimmed == "" {
            return
        }
        numberTxtField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        SendNumber()
    }
}
```

When I type `+98 912 123 1234` on the emulator it returns `09121231234` and when I do it on my device it returns `0 912 123 1234`.

Does anyone know why?

[this is my result on my device (iPhone 6s with ios 11.2.5):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cn04.png)

[this is my result on the emulator (iPhone 8 iOS 11.2):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw6ie.png)

Comment: Simulator & Device doesn't make any differences in this case

Comment: You can directly remove white space using `let trimmedString = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)`

Comment: Can you simplify the code and produce the same problem?  For example, try getting rid of everything after the first print().  Does replacingOccurrences() still fail on device?  Also, in case some other code could be modifying self.trimmed, try switching to a local variable as the result of replacingOccurrences().  Let's get to the crux of the fail.

Comment: I have used your code and it's working fine in device also.

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya, trimming character will remove whitespaces around from text, not from between.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya i know i tried that too still the same problem buddy...

Comment: @Smartcat yea i did that i simplified it 3 or 4 times and change it a bit but still the same problem not workin on the device

Comment: Can you share your device name and it's iOS version?

Comment: @iOSTeamI have iOS 11.2.5 running on iPhone 6s